# How to create basic authentication, login system for a web tool made in node.js and socket.io, without using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a web tool developed, which uses node.js and socket.io. it's a one page website and uses node.js for getting data from social media website and display on the same page. I would like to add a site specific login system for the website but don't want to use '[Express](http://expressjs.com/)' or '[Passport](http://passportjs.org/)' as it adds lots of overload to the website while it is not needed.

I am newbie with node.js and would like to know if I need to have a login system made with node.js to maintain session of the logged in user?

Note: I need to maintain session to log user data such as login time, search query and may be heatmap.

Thanks in advance. If needed I can explain specific part of the question in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like Express or Passport (or at least some of connect's middleware) will definitely be easier in the long run (if your app grows), but if you want to go the 'manual' route, here are some starting points:

1. Cookie Parser: You won't want to send the auth details with every request as a parameter, so you'll want to put the session details in a cookie. You can set cookies manually [using headers](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value), or with a node module that [wraps the API](https://github.com/jed/cookies) neatly.
2. Session Storage: You can put all the "login time, queries and heatmap data" in cookies, but it would be neater to just send a session id in the cookie in each request and save the other data server-side in a database. Options are [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose), redis, etc.

Since reading the source is very educational, go read connect's [cookieParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) and [cookieSession](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html). It's not a lot of code and the API docs include the actual source, so it's very easy to learn from. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

From how you are phrasing this question, I believe the overhead from using Express modules (Passport or similar) is the least of your worries ;-)

First you need to figure out which mechanisms you want to use.

For authentication, will you use a username/password combo, or will you be using a third party service like Google, Facebook, Twitter etc ("OAuth" like)? Unless you use some third party service, you also need to handle registration (and possibly verification of email address etc). Even for username/password combos, will you roll your own or use the browser based "basic-auth" mechanisms?

After authenticating you need a session mechanism to store some session token to recognize (and verify server side) that you have been authenticated. They are typically stored in browser cookies, which can easily be persisted for as long as you need, and are verified with each relevant request with tokens in a database on the server side.

And finally, you need a logout mechanism and a "I forgot my password" procedure (which may very well be manual initially...).

If all this is fairly new to you, I suggest trying to use something ready-made first (you mention Passport yourself), and then when you've mastered the basics, feel free to replace it with your own. The "upside" of using Passport or Everyauth is that they cover a lot more options that you realistically will be able to write yourself, so once you've adapted your system to use one of those, adding Facebook logins and similar will be a lot easier (somebody already figured out most of the stuff for your).

To be honest, most of the modules that handle such things in the Node ecosystem are fairly thin wrappers on top of whatever solution you decide to use, so the overhead will most likely not be substantial and you will most likely need a good understanding of the issues anyway to use them. At the other end of the spectrum are ready-made-systems like Drupal etc where everything just works, but then you're somewhat boxed in as far as making your own system.

There are use-cases where rolling your own from scratch is absolutely necessary, but there's nothing stopping your from doing this later when/if necessary (and after you've mastered the basics with the help of code that others wrote).

Best of luck!

Comment: I will have a paid subscribers, so I will be using a user/pass combo. I can see from other answers that, use of a middleware will be better approach for future growth. Thank you.