# Login System with expressjs + socket.io + redis + express-session

Tags: express, authentication, redis, socket.io

I wanted to build a login with chat system, with data getting stored.

I have chosen expressjs + socket.io and redis to do this. There are hell lot of resources on web, of which many are not working, because of older versions.
Below are links on stackoverflow, which have not given solution to my problem.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728111/how-to-create-basic-authentication-login-system-for-a-web-tool-made-in-node-js) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169418/how-can-i-get-sessions-to-work-using-redis-express-socket-io) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679046/expressjssocket-ioexpress-session)

I went across multiple passport npm packages, which is confusing me to use the right one.

[passport-socketio-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-socketio-redis), [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio),  [redis-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sessions),[passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport)

passport packages + Google plus login packages

[passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth), [passport-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google) ,[passport-google-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-plus/),[google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/)

Considering that I am newbie to MEAN stack, please suggest the right approach to get my login system with redis up and running. I am from PHP development background. Well [this link](http://tipstak.blogspot.in/2014/01/session-management-example-using-redis-on-express.html) helped me, but it is old version and not working.

Can somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're asking, you could do the following:

Express

- To render pages and handle form submission (user authentication etc).
- Use passport.js ([Local strategy](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password) for authentication management)

Redis

- Store user information (Username / Password)
- Session Storage (using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to handle the sessions & [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) for storage)

Socket.io

- For any real-time components of your applicaton (chat application)